# adSize not found, Android Studio not linking ad framework?

Tags: android, admob

I'm following https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-US#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk .

`<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8143809646615023/6347460003">
            >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>`

the error I get when building:

```

````
Android resource linking failed
Output:  /Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:29: error: attribute adSize (aka quantumpilot.quantumproductions.com.quantumpilot.app:adSize) not found.
/Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:29: error: attribute adUnitId (aka quantumpilot.quantumproductions.com.quantumpilot.app:adUnitId) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: /Users/quantum/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/502ec8114256bc9343b789f7637adf71/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/quantum/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
        --manifest\
        /Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debugFeature/processDebugFeatureManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/build/intermediates/processed_res/debugFeature/processDebugFeatureResources/out/resources-debugFeature.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugFeatureResources/resources-list-for-resources-debugFeature.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debugFeature/processDebugFeatureResources/r\
        --proguard\
        /Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/feature/build/intermediates/proguard-rules/feature/debug/aapt_rules.txt\
        --custom-package\
        quantumpilot.quantumproductions.com.quantumpilot.feature\
        -0\
        apk\
        --allow-reserved-package-id\
        --package-id\
        0x7e\
        -I\
        /Users/quantum/QuantumPilot/android/base/build/intermediates/processed_res/debugFeature/processDebugFeatureResources/out/resources-debugFeature.ap_\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```
````

Comment: did you add dependency on `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'`?

Comment: I sure did. I am seeing the test ad render successfully. That is fine. The problem is that it interrupts the rest of my rendering.

Comment: Oh I see you're trying to use that resource from the feature module. If you try to reference it from the base instead does it compile? Not sure if dependency resources are packaged into the base apk so that the feature could see them.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing the same error.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I just restarted my project and tried again, and got it working